# Preferred Video Sliders in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, video, revolution-slider

So I'm trying to create a slider with a video background (loaded externally) in wordpress. The video is on vimeo, but apparently the controls for the video player can't be hidden. Are there any recommended plugins or other video sites that would make the embed not only smooth, but easy to add layers to while hiding the video? Maybe I'm just using rev slider wrong?

Answer (score 1):

BigVideo is pretty common if you want a simple Javascript library to use: http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/